# Get column names of row if value is 1

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp

I have a table like:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Class  | Skill1 | Skill2 | Skill3 | Skill4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Strong |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| Tough  |      0 |      1 |      1 |      0 |
| Smart  |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Im trying to dynamically create a select dropdown on another page (This is not the problem). I want an Oracle SQL statement that can select the column names of all the columns that have a 1 in a specified row.

Example:
I choose Strong class and would like to know which skills I can use. So I need an SQL statement that will give me only the column names with a 1 in the field for just the Strong row. 
For this example, it should return (Skill1).

Comment: So you want a concatenated result? E.g. for Tough you want you result to be "Skill2,Skill3"

Comment: that would be correct. Also, there are like 30 columns. So the below methods would be tedious

Comment: In oracle, there is no way of doing unpivot dinamically, i wish that, so in this case (if you use unpivot) you need to harcode all columns, and yes it's a little tedious :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend changing your database structure -- what if you need to add another skill, you're going to have to keep adding new columns.  Consider creating a `skills` table and then relating those to classes via another table.  At that point, it's a simple `select` statement.

However, if that isn't an option in your case, one option using your current design would be to use `union all`:

```
select skill
from (
    select class, case when skill1 = 1 then 'Skill1' end Skill
    from yourtable
    union all 
    select class, case when skill2 = 1 then 'Skill2' end Skill
    from yourtable
    union all 
    select class, case when skill3 = 1 then 'Skill3' end Skill
    from yourtable
) t
where class = 'Strong' and skill is not null
```

Comment: You need to change doble quotes `""` by simple quote `''` when reference literals.

Comment: You're welcome man, i also like this approach, and think this is a little optimal than unpivot way

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpivot and then do a simple query where class = Strong and the skill = 1:

```
with t( Class  , Skill1 , Skill2 , Skill3 , Skill4 ) as 
(
select  'Strong' ,      1 ,      0 ,      0 ,      0 from dual union all
select  'Tough'  ,      0 ,      1 ,      1 ,      0 from dual union all 
select  'Smart'  ,      0 ,      0 ,      0 ,      1  from dual ) -- Sample data
select skills from (
select * from t
unpivot( 
skill for skills in (Skill1 , Skill2 , Skill3 , Skill4)
) ) where class = 'Strong' and skill = 1 ;
```